# Sharing memory between two threads, but address of data structures changes

Tags: multithreading, c++11, promise

I am using promises in C++, and have this really simple program. I create a promise, and pass it to a thread function **by reference**.

Inside the thread, I create a string and then set the promise's value to that string. Then in the main program, I retrieve the promise's value using a future. I'm confused about why the address of the string doesn't remain the same? Ideally it shouldn't vary between the threads since it belongs to shared memory right?

```
  void tfunc(promise<string> & prms) {
    string str("Hello from thread");
    cout << (void *)str.data() << endl;
    prms.set_value(str);
  }

  int main() {

    promise<string> prms;
    future<string> ftr = prms.get_future();
    thread th(&tfunc, ref(prms));
    string str = ftr.get();
    // This address should be the same as that inside the thread, right?
    cout << (void *)str.data() << endl;
    th.join();
    return 0;
  }
```

Comment: Why should the address be the same? Considering life-time issues the data in the promise have to be *copied*. If you rely on pointers being equal then perhaps your design is flawed?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Hey. I was following this tutorial: https://youtu.be/o0pCft99K74?t=618  (You can watch it at that exact time), and for him it seems to work. I also tried copying, but the address of the string still changes no matter what I do.

Comment: Make the string longer (to avoid small-string optimization), and make it `prms.set_value(std::move(str));` (otherwise `str` is copied into the promise) - [then it works](http://rextester.com/WCNXB8289). It's not necessary to pass a promise by reference; [this works, too](http://rextester.com/XBEJG5515)

Comment: @IgorTandetnik holy shit. I had no idea about small string optimization. Thanks a lot, I learned something cool from you!